# How can we Remove RRD config from Nagios?

Tags: nagios, rrd

I have Nagios setup for Passive monitoring and we don't use RRD data for any purpose. Is there a way to stop data storage and calculation at RRD. (intent here is to save system resource by stopping RRD calculation)

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in the main nagios.cfg for process_performance_data, set that to 0 and restart Nagios. 
https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html